# TypeError: Cannot read property 'SystemError' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jasmine, typeerror

I working in the Typescript and unittesting it with Jasmine . I have the code structure like

- Project

  - ParentPackage

    - ChildPackage

      - GrandChildPackage

        - fetchDetails.ts

    - DataFetchinglError.ts
  - AnotherParentPackage

  - errors.ts

fetchDetails.ts

```
import {ErrorType, ErrorameN, SystemError} from '../../AnotherParentPackage/system_error';

import {DataFetchinglError} from '../data_fetching_error';

  it('throws error if file not found', async () => {
    .
    .
    .
    await expectAsync(result).toBeRejectedWith(new DataFetchinglError(
        ErrorName.NO_SUCH_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY,
        ErrorType.GENERIC,
        `No file found at '${Location}'.`,
        ));
  });
```

DataFetchinglError.ts

```
import {ErrorType, SystemError} from '../../AnotherParentPackage/system_error';

export class DataFetchinglError extends SystemError {
  constructor(
      readonly name: number, readonly type: ErrorType,
      message: string) {
    // This call breaks the prototype chain, ...
    super(name, type, message);
    // ... so it has to be restored.
    // This requires ES6 transpilation, otherwise the compilation will fail.
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }

  toString() {
    return `${this.type}:${this.name} (${
        this.message || 'Undefined error.'})`;
  }
}
```

Error Class

```
export class ErrorType {
    .
    .
    ,
    constructor() {}
}

export const enum ErrorName{
    NONE,
    GENERIC
}

export class SystemError extends Error {
 constructor(
     readonly name: number, readonly type: ErrorType,
     message: string) {
    // This call breaks the prototype chain, ...
   super(message);
    // ... so it has to be restored.
    // This requires ES6 transpilation, otherwise the compilation will fail.
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }
```

On running this testcase I am getting these errors . It points to the .js files generated however upon clicking it says files doesn't exist anymore on runtime.

1. fetchDetails
   **-  TypeError: Cannot read property 'SystemError' of null**
2. Non-spec failure
   **- An error was thrown in afterAll
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'SystemError' of null**

I am also getting error in the logs and but read somewhere that it can be ignored

**error 'goog.require could not find: Anotherparenr.DataFetchinglError**

Error Interface

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

Comment: Can you share the Error class as well?

Comment: Its a generic class being extended by various class. Have added that as well.